# Submit form using jQuery is not working on IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, submit

Im using a form:

```
<form class="sortform" action="" method="get">
<select id="custom-search-filter" class="filter">
<option class="custom-search-order" value="ASC">Ascending</option>
<option class="custom-search-order" value="DESC">Descending</option>
</select>
</form>
```

to submit another form:

```
jQuery('select#custom-search-filter').change(function() {

    var order = jQuery(this).val();

    jQuery("div#custom-search-wrap #searchform input#order").val(order);

    jQuery('div#custom-search-wrap #searchform').submit();

});
```

The other form:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="http://mysite.lh/">

...

</form>
```

Form above is working, but is not working when the other select from the other form change.

But this is not working on IE7? Any help is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the HTML for the other form as well?

Comment: Guess: Both your forms have the same ID?

Comment: now i added the other form piece of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at your code and i cant find a form wich matches your

```
div#custom-search-wrap #searchform
```

selector.

This will work...

```
$(function() {
  alert($('div#custom-search-wrap #searchform').length) // 0 nothing found
  alert($(".sortform").length) // 1 form found
})
```

**Update**

You said that the form comes from another piece of code.

Please check your selector like i done it and compare the 
results in IE with firefox, chrome or etc.

**hope this helps**

Comment: Now works great when I added names and not just only ids to forms and to select field. Thanks man.